# SQL - How to hide column in select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables "contract" and "worker". I need to find the worker which has the most holidays left. However, I only need to print his name, not the holidays.

### SCHEMA

---

**Contract:**

```
Contract_ID (PK)
Worker_ID (FK)
holidays
```

**Worker**

```
Worker_ID (PK)
Name
```

### SAMPLE DATA:

---

**contract**
[image: Contract]

**worker**
[image: Worker]

### CODE

---

Currently I print the information out with this code:

**EDIT**: The following SQL Code is wrong! It shows `Fegelein` even though `Klink` is the person with the most holidays.

```
SELECT W.Name, MAX(C.Holidays) As Holidays 
FROM worker AS W, contract AS C
WHERE W.Worker_ID = C.Worker_ID
```

**Result:**

```
Name    Holidays
Fegelein    31
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Name
Fegelein
```

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a840b/17

So I need to hide the second select `MAX(C.Holidays) As Holidays`. Is this possible?

Comment: @GordonLinoff maybe you should read the question again, everything you asked for is included already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Or, as a comment I saw yesterday suggests . . . `JOIN` the modern world.

If you only want one such worker, then use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT w.Name
FROM worker w JOIN
     contract c
     ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_ID
ORDER BY c.Holidays DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

*Most* holidays appears to be the smallest value of `holiday`.  If it is the smallest value (as suggested by your question), use `ORDER BY c.Holidays ASC`.

Presumably, workers might be on multiple contracts, so you might want aggregation.  However, that is unclear.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a840b/31) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Result: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT w.Name FROM worker w JOIN contract c ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_' at line 5`

Comment: @Black Then you copied Gordon's query incorrectly, or the schema you showed us isn't accurate.

Comment: @Black . . . The code works fine on SQL Fiddle.  I've added the link.

Comment: Works! My fault, I had some other SQL Statements before and forgot to close one with `;`

Comment: But there seems to be a problem with the logic, since `Fegelein`appears even though `Klink` is the one with the most holidays. But the problem from the question is solved, which is what mathers. If I add `DESC` then `Klink`appears

Answer (score 4):

Simply try with :

```
SELECT w.Name
FROM worker w JOIN
     contract c
     ON w.Worker_ID = c.Worker_ID
ORDER BY c.Holidays DESC
```

You can add `LIMIT 1` if you need only one result.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do your job.

```
SELECT W.Name
FROM worker AS W, contract AS C
where W.Worker_ID = C.Worker_ID order by C.Holidays limit 1;
```

Delete Holidays  from select attributes and limit it to 1 and orderby Holidays  does the job

Comment: Thats very simple, I love it!

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -- the easiest way.

```
SELECT name
FROM (
    SELECT w.* , c.* 
    FROM worker w
    JOIN contract c 
    ON w.worker_id=c.worker_id
)
WHERE holidays = (
    SELECT max(holidays)
    FROM contract
);
```